# css table shadow outside not showing

Tags: css

**SOLVED**  - Solution is below, check the fiddle page how you do this on right way.

.

Mine problem is on the code below, that i want to achieve 2 shadows: 1 on the outside and 1 one the inside. Somehow now the code does the outside shadow making it disappear.

Here below i dropped the code on how i have it right now. I might do something wrong, only i do not know where.

**THE CODE:**

```
<style type="text/css">
body {
    background-image: url(grassbkg.png);
    background-color:#000;
}
.tablecorner {
    border-radius: 25px;
    padding-top: 8px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 8px;    
    border: 2px solid #FFFFFF;
    background-color: rgba(11, 66, 121, 0.7);
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
}
.tablecorner, outsideshadow {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 15px 8px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 15px 8px#000;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px 8px #000;
}
.tablecorner, shadowinside {
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 1px 1px 15px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 1px 1px 15px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow:inset 1px 1px 15px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
.tablecorner tr td {
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-shadow: 0px 2px #000000;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table align="center" class="tablecorner">
  <tr>
    <td align="left" valign="top">Dit is gewoon even een test om te zien dat alles gewoon naar behoren werkt, werkt het dan niet dan moeten we wat anders doen......</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

How do i fix this issue?

**Here i have also the code in fiddle:** [MyCodeInFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dononius/cr6f33w5/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add multiple box shadows you need to do it in 1 style rule, comma separated. Otherwise the 2nd rule overwrites the first

```
.tablecorner {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 15px 8px #000, inset 1px 1px 15px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 15px 8px#000, inset 1px 1px 15px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px 8px #000, inset 1px 1px 15px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
```

Comment: Aaahh okay, thx... was just wondering why it was not working. But now i understand it .